# Protecting against "-" symbol in filenames

Tags: bash, command-line, arguments

This question is loosely related to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/913526/295286). The basic idea is that OP had `-` in filename which broke `ls *.vcf`. What happened is clearly understood, but the question is then, how could one 'protect'  or anticipate such filenames with the wildcard expansion ? I know one could use `find` , but what about wildcard expansion in shell specifically ?

Comment: @don_crissti well . . . that was so obvious that I just feel stupid.  Write an answer.

Comment: or `ls -- ...` ...

Comment: `ls -- *.vcf`.  `--` is an argument which is available in many commands which is understood to mean "no more switches starting with `-` from this point".

Comment: @JeffSchaller that's not 100% reliable, not all commands have that option.  But yeah . . .it's a dupe of what don_crissti linked. Just VTC